# MATLAB: using a minimum function within symsum

Tags: matlab, min, symbolic-math

I am trying to run code similar to the following, I replaced the function I had with one much smaller, to provide a minimum working example:

```
clear
syms k m
n=2;
symsum(symsum(k*m,m,0,min(k,n-k)),k,0,n)
```

I receive the following error message:

"Error using sym/min (line 86)
Input arguments must be convertible to floating-point numbers."

I think this means that the min function cannot be used with symbolic arguments. However, I was hoping that MATLAB would be substituting in actual numbers through its iterations of `k=0:n`.

Is there a way to get this to work? Any help much appreciated. So far I the most relevant page I found was [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102485-why-are-symbolic-variables-not-allowed-when-using-the-functions-max-min-in-the-symbolic-math-toolbox), but I am somewhat hesitant as I find it difficult to understand what this function does.

EDIT following @horchler, I messed around putting it in various places to try and make it work, and this one did:

```
clear
syms k m
n=2;
symsum(symsum(k*m,m,0,feval(symengine, 'min', k,n-k)),k,0,n)
```

Because I do not really understand this `feval` function, I was curious to whether there was a better, perhaps more commonly-used solution. Although it is a different function, there are many pieces online advising against the `eval` function, for example. I thought perhaps this one may also carry issues.

Comment: Did you try the `feval`-based solution provided at the link in your question? It works for R2015a at least.

Comment: @horchler. Thanks, I've edited my question. Is this what you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that Matlab should be able to solve this as you expect, even though the documentation is clear that it won't.

**Why the issue occurs**
The problem is due the inner symbolic summation, and the `min` function itself, being evaluated first:

```
symsum(k*m,m,0,min(k,n-k))
```

In this case, the input arguments to [`sym/min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/min.html) are not "convertible to floating-point numbers" as `k` is a symbolic variable. It is only after you wrap the above in another symbolic summation that `k` becomes clearly defined and could conceivably be reduced to numbers, but the inner expression has already generated an error so it's too late.

I think that it's a poor choice for `sym/min` to return an error. Rather, it should just return itself. This is what the [sym/int](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) function does when it can't evaluate an integral symbolically or numerically. [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-mupad.html) (see below) and Mathematica 10 also do something like this as well for their min functions.

**About the workaround**
This directly calls a MuPAD's [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/min.html) function. Calling MuPAD functions from Matlab is discussed in more detail in [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html) from The MathWorks.

If you like, you can wrap it in a function or an anonymous function to make calling it cleaner, e.g.:

```
symmin =  @(x,y)feval(symengine,'min',x,y);
```

Then, you code would simply be:

```
syms k m
n = 2;
symsum(symsum(k*m,m,0,symmin(k,n-k)),k,0,n)
```

If you look at the code for `sym/min` in the Symbolic Math toolbox (type `edit sym/min` in your Command Window), you'll see that it's based on a different function: `symobj::maxmin`. I don't know why it doesn't just call MuPAD's `min`, other than performance reasons perhaps. You might consider filing a [service request](http://www.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/contact_us/?s_tid=gn_cntus) with The MathWorks to ask about this issue.